# Wildfly and https

Tags: jakarta-ee, https

I've created a JAXRS REST API and it's in a Wildfly 10 server. I'm really looking forward to knowing what do I need to do in order to set the communications works on a `https` instead of `http`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is to setup SSL in Wildfly itself.  [This guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=66322705) can help you through this process and it will work for Wildfly 8 on up.

The other way is to front Wildfly with [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org), a very popular web server.  The [Apache SSL docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) go into ways to do this.  Note that if you go this route you'll also then need to understand things like [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) and possibly [mod_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html).

Using Apache does change your administrative procedures a bit.  However, if you decided to get either a commercial SSL certificate or a [free one](https://letsencrypt.org/) support for Apache is likely to be more widespread than Wildfly.